# FONT_AWESOME icon in PrimeFaces ribbon not properly displayed

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces, font-awesome

I am Facing a situation where each **FONT_AWESOME** icon is displayed at the bottom inside any action button in the Primefaces Ribbon thus hidding the tex that should be display for each button.
I tried overriding using lot of messy css but, with no success

my action button code in the ribbon

```
<p:commandButton value="New" icon="fa fa-camera-retro fa-3x" styleClass="ui-ribbon-bigbutton myButton" type="button" />
```

here my custom css code

```
myButton{

    display: block;
}

.fa{
   vertical-align: top; 
}
```

[image]    I want it to be formated like this[image]

I'm using **primefaces 5.2** with **glassfish 4.1**

Answer (score -1):

edited as follows:

```
<style type="text/css">           
        .ui-icon.fa{
           margin-top: -22px !important;
        }

    </style>
```

You can solve this way

Comment: This answer makes **all** fa icons move up. Please make the answer more specific for the ribbon

Comment: But what if I also use these in normal buttons, or in a plain div or?